# Is domain name of the server checked during SSL handshake

Tags: ssl, dns

During SSL handshake, is the domain name of the server checked during SSL handshake,  I mean is the domain name in the server certificated checked against the domain in which server is running ?

Example: Suppose Server certificate has domain mydomain.com . And if server is running in domain someotherdomain.com ...  Is this cheked during SSL handshake and aborted as mydomain.com is not someotherdomain.com ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends...

The SSL/TLS standard itself doesn't specify how and when the server certificate is verified.

From the [introduction](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-1):

> [...] the decisions on how to initiate TLS handshaking and how to interpret the authentication certificates exchanged are left to the judgment of the designers and implementors of protocols that run on top of TLS.

This being said, while it doesn't specify how the authentication has to take place, implementations are meant to perform this check during the handshake (or at the very least, immediately after):

- See [Appendix D](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-D.2).
- Some [error messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2.2) are clearly related to certificate authentication failure (`bad_certificate`, `certificate_expired`, ...).
- Some of the text in the [handshake overview](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.3): "*[...] If the server is authenticated, it may request a certificate from the client, if that is appropriate to the cipher suite selected.*"

In most cases, the certificate verification itself is guided by [RFC 3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280)/[RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280).
A number of SSL/TLS stacks will at least do this by default.

The host name verification, which could be considered as one of the certificate authentication step, has historically been implemented separately. This is mainly because RFC 3280/RFC 5280 didn't address this step and left it to each application protocol. There is a relatively recent harmonisation attempt in [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) (you can find the differences in protocols in Appendix B).

Whether host name checking is done during the SSL/TLS handshake depends on the library you're using, and how you've configured it.

For example, before Java 7, this had to be done separately from the main JSSE API (`SSLSocket`/`SSLEngine`). (This was done in `HttpsURLConnection`, for example, but this sits on top of the JSSE, not within.) Since Java 7, it's possible to perform this check during the handshake and within the JSSE using the [`X509ExtendedTrustManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html), but this has to be configured using [`SSLParameters.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979954/372643), which [only supports `HTTPS` and `LDAPS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#jssenames) (this being said, even if your service doesn't use HTTP, using `HTTPS` for the endpoint identification algorithm wouldn't be a bad choice, certainly better than nothing).

Other SSL/TLS libraries or wrapping other libraries in other languages tend at least to have callbacks for this. Whether they're used (and used correctly) by developers depends, as shown in [this paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eshmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf). (You might also be interested in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/22965/2435) on Security.SE.)

Answer (score 0):

No. Hostname checking is part of HTTPS, not SSL.

Comment: The question didn't say a single word about HTTPS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. During SSL handshake proper client should compare the hostname it connects to with the domain name(s) specified in the certificate. Not doing so would make TLS useless, as MITM attacks would be trivial otherwise.

Note that there exists many badly written software that accepts any presented certificates an doesn't do proper certificate validation. Recently there was a report on this issue in regards to Android software. It appeared that thousands of offered software titles (mainly freeware) don't perform proper validation thus imposing security risks to their users.

Comment: SSL/TLS assumes that private key of server is not compromised. RFC 6125 addresses this issue if MITM which is implemented by HTTPS if I am correct.

Comment: @user1197140 Authenticity of the server is to be checked in one way or another (for certificates it's a validation procedure but TLS supports not just certificate-based authentication). Whether the key is compromised or not - that's a *totally* different story. Check of the address (or domain name) is to ensure that you are connecting to the expected server A and that MITM doesn't present a certificate issued for server B.